# Why does Mike call Jimmy "Saul"?

Tags: breaking-bad, better-call-saul

In *Breaking Bad*, Mike clearly calls Jimmy by his alternate name "Saul" multiple times. In *Better Call Saul,* we see that their paths are crossed quite considerably before Jimmy even starts using his alter ego of Saul Goodman.

Why does Mike entertain this alter ego name? He doesn't seem to be the type of guy who would do so, regardless of Jimmy's reasons for using it. It seems to be a bit of a plot hole (granted, it isn't a big one). I can see why someone would disagree with me on this point, but Gilligan's style is so careful and thought-out that it's surprising that something like this would be left unturned. Concepts of *Better Call Saul* were thought of well before *Breaking Bad* had finished airing, so I would've thought they had plenty of time to close any of these holes.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I disagree that Mike isn't the sort of person who would entertain a name change like this.  Mike is *exactly* the sort of person who would hear "I've changed my name to Saul" and shrug it off with a casual "Whatever," and then proceed to call him only Saul from then on.

Mike is the kind of guy who does the job he's asked to do and doesn't ask any questions that he doesn't need the answers to.  As long as you play it straight, he will too.

Refusing to call Jimmy "Saul" would potentially disrupt any shady dealings they were involved in together, if third parties only knew the name Saul.  It would also be an indiscretion to casually blow Saul's cover by calling him Jimmy just because Mike knows his real name.  Of all the characters seen in *either* show, Mike is the *most* discreet and conscientious of the sensitive nature of the illegal operations these people so often find themselves embroiled in.

Unless he had a good reason NOT to call Jimmy "Saul," I believe he would do so without batting an eyelash.

Comment: Well I couldn't of asked for a better answer. Never thought of it that way. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: "(...) I believe he would do so without batting an eyelash." I literally thought of Mike's dead stare while reading this.

Comment: To be fair, it seems to be a fairly open "secret"--Saul outs himself as actually being named "McGill" completely unprompted, the first time he meets Walter, when he (falsely) mentions that he's Irish. I can definitely see Mike shrugging and going "sure, whatever" though.

Comment: @MiloP True, but the point here is that *Mike* wouldn't let it slip.  If Saul lets it slip himself, that's his choice and/or problem.

Comment: Didn't he also tell the idiot in BEtter Call Saul (the guy who buys the Hummer) specifically to not use his real name in his shady dealings? It stands to reason that Mike then agrees with Jimmy's assumed identity (though the circumstances of Jimmy becoming Saul are not yet set in stone in Better Call Saul).

Comment: @Steve-O, excellent analysis of Mike.

Comment: Yes, if anyone would value the use of fake names it would be someone who is in the line that Mike is in. On the other hand, it would be "civilians" who would be resistant to changing the name they used for someone, probably make dangerous mistakes in front of people. It reminds me of when Saul almost spilled the beings by accidentally calling his client "Lalo" when he was known by a completely different name to the people he was talking to. They say it is much harder to lie than tell the truth which is also explore when Lalo interrogates Saul after the events in the desert.